# Location response header returned from web-api to Swagger-ui

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, response-headers

I am returning a Uri as the location header of the response from my web-api controller, as shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostTenant([FromBody] JObject value)
{
    string tenantName;
    try
    {
        tenantName = value.GetValue("name").ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e));
    }

    try
    {
        DbInteract.InsertTenant(tenantName.Replace(" ", string.Empty));
        var uri = Url.Link("TenantHttpRoute2", new { tenantName });
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
    catch...
}
```

The swagger-ui client makes the **POST** request, but the response headers don't contain the  **Location** uri. It appears like this:

[POST request from Swagger-ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki65P.png)

As you can see in the image, the **RESPONSE HEADERS** are 
{
  "content-type": null
}

---

The swagger JSON for this post request is:

```
        "post": {
            "tags": [
                "Tenant"
            ],
            "summary": "Add a new tenant",
            "description": "Adds a tenant and returns admin user account information to be used in further calls.",
            "consumes": [
                "application/json",
                "application/xml"
            ],
            "produces": [
                "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "body",
                    "name": "Tenant",
                    "description": "Name of the tenant must be alphanumeric without any special characters.",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/CreateTenant"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "201": {
                    "description": "Tenant Inserted",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "description": "Location",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "400": {
                    "description": "Invalid JSON Format of input"
                },
                "405": {
                    "description": "Tenant by this name already exists; Use PUT instead"
                },
                "500": {
                    "description": "InternalServerError"
                }
            }
        }
```

---

What's wrong here? Why can't I see the response header in swagger-ui? Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The intent seems clear enough: a successful response returns a 201 Created with a Location header pointing at the newly created resource.  Should work ...

I might remove the "produces" attribute, since you haven't defined any response anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
"headers" : {  "Location" : { "description": "...", "type" : "string" } }
```

Instead of:

```
"headers" : []
```

so object instead of arrays.

Comment: To improve your answer maybe you can format source code